# sql query syntax for limit minimum maximum range values

Tags: mysql

I am new here. I have some issue in my sql query. I am writing sql query in my java code that gets three values from the user (limit, min, max) and show the records in between the minimum and maximum range. Such as if the user want to see 10 records and in between 5 to 100 transaction value. i am struggling in figuring out the correct syntax of the query. My query is

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(""
                 + "Select Transaction_ID, Transaction_Value, Transaction_Type, Description  "
                 + "from Banking "
                 + "limit ? "
                 + "where MIN(Transaction_Value) = ? AND "
                 + "MAX(Transaction_Value) = ? ");

        //setting the limit of records, minimum and maximum values specified by the user
        statement.setInt(1, num);
        statement.setInt(2, min);
        statement.setInt(3, max);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

When I execute this query, it prompt an error message that

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MIN(Transaction_Value) = 5 AND MAX(Transaction_Value) = 100' at line 1..
```

Your help will be really appreciated. I am really very much struggling. I have used simple queries before but dot know how to fix that error.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: limit must come after where clause

Comment: You have multiple errors in your basic SQL syntax.  I would suggest that you review some *basic* material on the language -- until you understand that `limit` is the last statement and aggregation functions do not belong in the `where` clause.

Comment: "I have some issue" Indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min` and `max` are just range values in your query - there's no need to apply aggregate functions. Additionally, the `limit` clause should come after the `where` clause:

```
SELECT Transaction_ID, Transaction_Value, Transaction_Type, Description  FROM   Banking
WHERE  Transaction_Value >= ? AND
       Transaction_Value <= ? 
LIMIT  ?
```

Answer (score 0):

....`WHERE Transaction_Value BETWEEN 5 AND 100;`

MIN and MAX should be always used in a GROUP BY clause for more than 1 row

```
SELECT MAX(daily_typing_pages)
     FROM employee_tbl;

SELECT id, name, MAX(daily_typing_pages)
    FROM employee_tbl GROUP BY name;
```